# New rotors and brake pads screeching sound

Tags: brake-rotor, lexus

I own a 2011 lexus ES350. I just changed the front rotors and brake pads. But i get a very bad screeching sound when i push the brake. Is this normal with new rotors and pads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should **not** be a screeching noise when you use the brakes. (I take it that you mean the screeching sound is when you drive the vehicle.) You will have to dismantle the brakes to the extent that you did to replace your rotors and pads. You must check that the rotors and discs are exactly the same size and profile as the ones replaced. Check any bolts removed, especially for length and have been replaced into their correct holes and correctly tightened. Check the caliper sliding bolts are in the correct holes and for lengths and that they are not seizing. Anti-rattle springs fitted correctly and in place. Anti-squeal shims correctly fitted and on the correct side of the vehicle (check for arrows or indicators showing direction of rotation, they should point to the front of the vehicle). If every thing is exactly like it should be the chances are you have sub-standard or counterfeit parts and you should raise the matter with your supplier. Toyota/Lexus do not screech on brake application.

Answer (score 0):

did you bed your brakes in? 1.make 8-10 gentle stops from 30-15mph. at 30 sec. intervals.
2.make 8-10 moderate stops from 45-30mph. at 30 sec. intervals.3.make 8-10 hard stops 
from 55-65mph. to 25mph. at 30 sec. intervals